# Delete query with MIN() function

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with this query:

I want to delete records where *username*  and *upload_time*  is specific.

Here is my Query:

```
DELETE FROM [upload_news] 
WHERE (SELECT MIN[upload_time] 
FROM [upload_news] 
WHERE [username]='"+username+"');
```

How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

Change Like This

```
DELETE FROM [upload_news] WHERE upload_time=
(SELECT min(upload_time) FROM [upload_news] WHERE 
 [username]='"+username+"')
```

Comment: @user3419496 now check it

Comment: please, note that another user might have uploaded news at the same time.